# How do I access uploaded images in refinery cms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I'm pretty sure that there should be an easy way of doing this. I already tried out to override the models and discovered that the imagines seem to get saved in the database.
All i want it to be able to show all the oploaded images in the application view, so that they can be displayed on every page.

Currently I am new to Rails, I would be thankful for an easy guide or at least some hints.

Answer (score 1):

They're saved as Image model instances and you can use the image_fu view helper to render them in whatever size you need.  So in your view just do something along the lines of

```
<% Image.all.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_fu image, "100x100", :id => dom_id(image) %>
<% end %>
```